# QUESTION ON TOR ANONIMIZATION

Tags: security, windows, help

I have the following question:

I downloaded a file through Torbrowser, clicking on it I was asked to open an external sw out to Torbrowser.
If i start that sw are still in anonymous mode or not?

Comment: By downloading anything from Tor, your anonymity is at risk. If you must, in short, you are not safe.

Comment: That's a very broad and bold claim to make. Care to elabourate with more details for the questioner to better understand?

Comment: In practice with TOR you are anonymous just browsing with the Torbrowser while you are not anonymous using sw outside the Torbrowser.
Did I get it right?

Comment: Sure, but the what your answer says is *downloading* from Tor puts you at risk. Opening it does, simply downloading it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you open a file downloaded through Tor Browser in external software it will no longer be anonymous and might make a connection to the internet outside of Tor which can deanonymize you.

See my answer to [*"is it safe to download files through TOR?"*](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/15974/12737) for more details on the specifics. I can't flag this as a duplicate of that question because no one has voted or accepted the answer.